# How to populate a subclass of System.Data.DataTable with data?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have a class that derives from `DataTable`. In its ctor, I'd like it to have all the data from a `DataTable` object I fetch from a call to a function.

This sounds like a very trivial thing but I am surprised that I can't figure it out. Sorry, I've been coding for over 12 hours straight and so I think I am phased out.

Help will be appreciated.

```
using System.Data;
using Foo.Data;

namespace Foo.BusinessObjects
{
    public class StringTable : DataTable
    {
        public StringTable() : base()
        {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM FooBar";


            // I know that that's not a legal C# statement but 
            // if it were, I'd want to do the equivalent of the following:

            this = Database.DefaultDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);


        }
    }
}
```

Where the `GetDataTable` method returns a `System.Data.DataTable` object. It's signature is here:

```
public DataTable GetDataTable(string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
   DataSet dataset;

   return ((dataset = GetDataSetInternal(sql, false, parameters)) == null ? 
            null : dataset.Tables[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the below line in the constructor of the derived class

```
this = Database.DefaultDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);
```

with

```
DataTable dtResult = Database.DefaultDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);
this.Merge(dtResult);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That was *just* what I was looking for -- something to manipulate the internal state with. You're da man!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this kind of thing in a constructor. You could favour composition over inheritance and still have your StringTable class.

```
public class StringTable
{
    private DataTable dataTable;

    public StringTable()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM FooBar";


        // I know that that's not a legal C# statement but 
        // if it were, I'd want to do the equivalent of the following:

        dataTable = Database.DefaultDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);
    }
}
```

Another option is look towards factory patterns working with DataTable rather than subclassing it. Something along these lines. Inheritance is really only to give you benefit if it can behave in polymorphic way. Otherwise I am not sure you gain anything,

```
public class DataTableFactory
{
    public DataTable CreateStringTable()
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM FooBar";
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        return Database.DefaultDatabase.GetDataTable(sql);
    }

    public DataTable CreateSomeOtherTable()
    {
       //etc etc
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, dan. I considered both these options (and a few others -- to have a generic resource table factory). All your options make sense. I was just hoping to have a more intuitive, clean API that allowed the client to say: `GridView.DataSource = new StringTable();` and voila! I'm still looking into the source code for `DataAdapter.Fill` (a protected virtual internal method to see the magic but its filled with labels and `goto`s and obfuscated identifiers). If all else fails, that's where I'll be going -- with what you recommended and I have considered already as a fall back.